# How can I permanently forget T4 generated files from being version control using Mercurial?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, t4, visualhg

How can I permanently forget T4 generated files from being version control using Mercurial?

It seems that Visual Studio (VisualHG) automatically adding them to version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hg forget`, and then add the generated files to your `.hgignore` file so they won't get added again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`hg forget` command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#forget) which will remove files from version control, but without deleting them from your working copy. The files **will** be deleted from everybody else's working copies when they pull the changeset and update.

You'll probably also want to add the files to your `.hgignore` file so that you know they stay unversioned.

Comment: Yea, but I can never remember what it is. ;-)

Comment: MikeD: I'm not sure I get it -- have you forgotten the forget command? :-)